# Excel VBA dump SQL Query into Array not to ListObject

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, vba

I am creating a SQL query to get data from an SQL database, but the macro recorder posts the data into a listobject. I want the query to post the data into an array instead of listobject.

```
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Query1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Query1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Query1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: If you used an ADODB.RecordSet object to capture the query results then you could use its GetRows method to transfer them directly to an array

Comment: A `ListObject` by definition exists on a worksheet... so no, you can't use `.ListObjects.Add` to directly create an array.

Comment: I am just using the macro recorder to get the data from the SQL database. 
Not sure how to bypass this and use ADODB instead..

Comment: If you use ADO to run the query you can't use the macro recorder - luckily there are plenty of previous posts here or via Google if you search "VBA ADO".  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic?view=sql-server-ver15